# Calculating the Running Corrleation of two signals in Matlab

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, signal-theory

I am currently using https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs206/public/lab/ to advance my matlab skills. Sadly I am stuck at lab2 task 2. First, i cant run the pcode file to get the proper solution because matlab always complains about `Warning: Skipping argument 'run_corr_demo', no MATLAB code found.> In pcode (line 211)`

and my second problem is the output of the correlation, which should be zero because there is no correlation between these signals right?
[image]
Running Correlation of Code1 and Code 3
Maybe anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong?
Here my code:

```
function out = run_corr(x,y);
%function out = run_corr(x,y);
%
% RUN_CORR -- This function implements the "real-time" running
% correlation algorithm.
%
% Input Parameters:
% x -- the signal to correlate with (i.e., the transmitted signal)
% y -- the signal to correlate against (i.e., the received signal)
%
% Output Parameters:
% out -- the resulting correlation signal with size equal to
% length(x) + length(y) - 1
% Written by Mark Bartsch, Winter 2002
% Modification History:
% 8/16/02 -- Added modification history (MB)
% Initialize the output vector to all zeros. It should have
% length(x) + length(y) - 1 elements.
out = zeros(1,length(x)+length(y)-1);
% Make x and y column vectors, regardless of incoming size
x = x(:);
y = y(:);
x = x.';
% Beyond the end of the signal y, the input is zero
y(end+1:end+length(x)) = 0;
% Buffer is just a column vector. We initialize it to
% all zeros (with the same size as x) to begin with.
buffer = zeros(size(x));
for n = 1:length(out)
% current_sample is the single-sample input to our "correlation box"
current_sample = y(n);
% Update the buffer. Discard the first sample in the buffer, and put
% current_sample at the end of the buffer.
buffer = ([buffer(2:end), current_sample]);
% From x and the contents of buffer, we can calculate
% the next output sample
out(n) = x*buffer.';
end
```

Comment: `p-code` seems to be some type of encoded Matlab function file. Did you try to run the file downloaded without changing it in anyway ? Maybe the file is corrupted.

Comment: I get the figure that you have posted when I run `plot(xcorr(code2, code1));` and not `code3` as implied in the question. Why do you think the correlation should be zero ?

Comment: The correlation at sample `100` is correct as you can verify by doing `sum(code1 .* code2)`. You can try manually verifying some output samples.

Comment: To be honest I only ever seen "normal" correlation. That's why the signal looks total garbage to me. And yes I ploted it like you suggested